# Caminho correto para chegar em uma pasta fora do servidor www utilizando php e linux

Tags: php, linux, path

Tenho um programa em php em um servidor linux e queria saber como é possivel meu arquivo acessar um elemento que está fora da pasta www.
por exemplo, tenho a pasta www e uma pasta para o meu projeto onde tem minha pagina principal index.php

porém tenho o seguinte diretorio

```
/var 
  /www
     /Projeto
       /index.php
```

e no mesmo nivel da pasta www tenho uma pasta chamada spool e outra chamada imagens.

ficando

```
/var
   /spool
      /imagens
```

como eu consigo referenciar o caminho de uma imagem de dentro da minha aplicação php tendo acesso até uma imagem da pasta imagens por exemplo?
atualmente uso uma string strcaminho, que fica com o seguinte valor

strcaminho= "/var/spool/imagens/logo.png";

mas não consigo acessar, qual é a forma correta de se obter o caminho de um arquivo de fora da minha pasta www de acordo com as pastas?